# Help with summation

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, discrete-mathematics

I have been working on the following summation, which is a part of some bigger problem.

> $\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} \frac{i}{2(n-2)}$

Now I am stuck, because non of the formulas, that I know, seem to be suitable. 
I tried to solve it in so many ways, but I get a wrong answer-- compared to what the professor obtained.

Comment: Did it occur to you that the denominator, being a constant, can be ruled out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

If you know this formula:

$$\sum_{k=1}^ak=\frac{a(a+1)}2$$

Then you know this:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\frac i{2(n-2)}=\frac1{2(n-2)}\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}i=\frac1{2(n-2)}\frac{(n-2)(n-1)}2=\frac{n-1}4$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great help. Just one inquiry, is that because the term 2(n−2), is a constant-- its value is not gonna change in each iteration ?

Comment: Yes, constants can be pulled out of a sum.  In general:$$\sum c(a_k+b_k)=c\left[\sum a_k+\sum b_k\right]$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I was confused, and now I am all set.